# Unable to capture just one of two quotes

Tags: regex, powershell, ini

So I'm working off of [this blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/20/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file/) in an attempt to parse `ini` files.  It works for the most part, but I'm running into a specific problem I don't know enough about `regex` to solve.

---

### *Code sample:*

```
function Get-IniContent
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([hashtable])]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $PSItem -PathType Leaf})]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string]
        $Path
    )

    process
    {
        $ini = @{}

        switch -Regex -File $Path
        {
            '^\[(?<Section>.+)\]$'
            {
                $section = $Matches['Section']
                $ini[$section] = @{}
                $commentCount = 0
            }

            '^;(?<Comment>.*)'
            {
                if (-not $section)
                {
                    $section = 'NoSection'
                    $ini[$section] = @{}
                }
                $commentCount += 1
                $ini[$section]["Comment$commentCount"] = $Matches['Comment']
            }

            '(?<Key>.+?)\s*=\s*(?<Value>.*)'
            {
                if (-not $section)
                {
                    $section = 'NoSection'
                    $ini[$section] = @{}
                }

                $ini[$section][$Matches['Key']] = $Matches['Value'] -replace
                    '^"(.*)"$', '$1' -replace
                    '\s*(.*)\s*', '$1'
            }
        }

        $ini
    }
}
```

---

### *The problem:*

In this section:

```
$ini[$section][$Matches['Key']] = $Matches['Value'] -replace
     '^"(.*)"$','$1' -replace
     '\s*(.*)\s*','$1'
```

I'm running into cases where my `ini` files may have quoted values that then have strings with quotes:

```
Key="  this value="something here""
```

I want a single regex string (ideally in the switch capture) to avoid those surrounding double-quotes.

I tried using the optional character `"?` around both sides of the value, but it only managed to skip the starting quote, but not the ending quote.

---

### *Edit*

Sample string:

```
KeyName = "value:"ac-dii-sk""
```

Attempted pattern:

```
$HashPattern = '\s*(?<Key>.+)\s*=\s*"?\s*(?<Value>.*)\s*"?\s*'
```

Results:

```
$Matches['Key']   = KeyName
$Matches['Value'] = value:"ac-dii-sk""
```

Desired results:

```
$Matches['Key']   = KeyName
$Matches['Value'] = value:"ac-dii-sk"
```

Comment: @BenH Nope, that project is still the same as the post.

Comment: You might want to look at [Carbon](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Carbon/) or for something more specialized / lightweiight, [PsIni](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/). But if you still want to roll your own, please post the pattern you tried that uses `"?`, and please elaborate on the key/value. The one you supplied appears to be invalid, isn't it? Where is the key supposed to end in that example? Where does the value begin? Are quotes supposed to work like quotes or be ignored?

Comment: @briantist So my goal is to not capture starting/finishing quotes if they exist.  I'll update my post with what I'm trying.

Comment: Ok that's a bit better but now your sample pattern doesn't match your sample string. It's also not fully clear what part this string is the vaue and which part _designates_ the value; so in addition to showing the unsuccessful result, can you tell us what you _want_ the result to be? To sum up, show: an actual input string, an actual pattern to apply, what you get now, what you want.

Comment: @briantist Done.  I don't know if this is possible, but I only want the surrounding quotes to be replaced if both of them exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's give it a try with [Balancing Capture Groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html).

```
(?<Key>.+?)\s*=\s*(?<open>")?(?<Value>.*?)(?<close-open>")?$
```

#### [Test it Online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3CKey%3E.%2B%3F%29%5Cs*%3D%5Cs*%28%3F%3Copen%3E%22%29%3F%28%3F%3CValue%3E.*%3F%29%28%3F%3Cclose-open%3E%22%29%3F%24&i=KeyName%20%3D%20%22value%3A%22ac-dii-sk%22%22)

Input: `KeyName = "value:"ac-dii-sk""`
Captured Value: `value:"ac-dii-sk"`

Input: `KeyName = "value:"ac-dii-sk"` (1 fewer end quote)
Value: `value:"ac-dii-sk`

Input: `KeyName = value:"ac-dii-sk""` (missing beginning quote)
Value: `value:"ac-dii-sk""`

Input: `KeyName = value:"ac-dii-sk"` (no surrounding quotes)
Value: `value:"ac-dii-sk"`

---

As I mentioned in a comment, I recommend you just use an existing library to parse INI files. Here are 2 from PSGallery:

- [Carbon](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Carbon/)
- [PsIni](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was aiming for.  I didn't know about that feature, thanks!

Comment: Any idea why it would not work without that end boundary on it? `$`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 because I had to make the `.*` in the `Value` group non-greedy with `.*?`, otherwise, the dot will consume all the quotes, and if I didn't anchor the `close-open` group to the end, the non-greedy `value` group will capture as little as possible to satisfy the whole match, which in this case would be nothing, because the `close-open` group is optional.