# How to split weird string into correct parts

Tags: powershell

I get a string like this `"ABC","edf",1.2,75,"zzz10"",763,"abc, fgh"` from a program and I need to split it with PowerShell to this expected end result: `ABC|edf|1.2|75|zzz10"|763|abc, fgh`

My idea is to split the string in a way to create an array, which i then can `-join '|'`

the thing is - i can't just `-split` or `-replace` the chars `,` and `"` because if the are surrounded by `""` they need to be in the end result

how would you go for that?

Comment: To me, this looks like an aray with strings nearly quoted and numbers unquoted. No need to split, simply join with `|`. What does `$weirdstring.GetType()` show you?

Comment: @Theo i get this passed as one string from another program. they basically do `& myScript.ps1 "weirdString"` - if i try to make this an array by just wrapping it into `@()` it's a syntax error because of the `"zzz10""` part

Comment: Consider [balancing capture groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948012/unable-to-capture-just-one-of-two-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

The nested single quote in the substring `"zzz10""` needs to be doubled to make the data proper CSV. After that you can process it like this:

```
$s = '"ABC","edf",1.2,75,"zzz10"",763,"abc, fgh"'

$s -replace '"",', '""",' |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header a,b,c,d,e,f,g |
    ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -join '|' }
```